# I keep on getting the same error in the newest version of python

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, helper

So on python (Discord.py mainly) i keep getting the same error on a "$move" command how do i fix it.

the error is

```
python -u "/Users/ats/Desktop/bot.py"
iMac:~ ats$ python -u "/Users/ats/Desktop/bot.py
  File "/Users/ats/Desktop/bot.py", line 8
    async def on_ready():
        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me.

[Here is my code: (Click this blue text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGkpS.png)

------------------------------------------
NOTE:
i have no experience in coding

Comment: Have you tried importing `asyncio`? Also, don't attach images, post code into your question directly surrounded by triple backticks.

Comment: what is the output when you do `python --version` on the same terminal?

Comment: in the bottom left corner, it says python 3.9.7. which should work. but I believe MacOS comes with python 2.7 installed by default, please check if that's the case using `python --version`

Comment: "I have no experience in coding"... Before asking a question you need to understand the language you are coding in. [Here's how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Like `@WasiMaster` said, try the command `python3` instead of `python` to see if the issue is regarding that.

Comment: Also seems like you forgot the commas in the `embed` variable. `embed = discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description=e, colour=discord.Color.red()`

Answer (score 0):

u change your on_ready with this

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"we have logged in as {client.user}")
```